# objectify composite filter implementation or hack

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

It would appear that Objectify does not support the Datastore's `CompositeFilter`. But objectify does take `Filter`s. So for now how do I implement a composite `AND` filter in objectify? I am moving from Datanucleus and I need the query

```
"SELECT f.healthy FROM Food f WHERE  f.fan = :userid AND flavor = : flavor";
```

So the type is `Food.class` and the fields are `fan` and `flavor`

Comment: Both of the below answers are correct. The insight you are missing is that `CompositeFilter` extends `Filter`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a composite filter and pass that to ofy query variant which accepts filter.

```
CompositeFilterOperator.and(
     FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("f.fan", userId),
     CompositeFilterOperator.or(
         FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("flavor", flavor),
         FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("color", color)));
```

However, implementing OR filters have its own side effects; for e.g. you can't use cursors.

Ref of above code: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query.CompositeFilter

Answer (score 0):

Queries are quite simple:

```
List<Food> foods = ofy().load().type(Food.class).filter("fan", xxx).filter("flavor", xxx).list();
```

**make sure all fields you plan to filter/sort on are marked with @Index** before persisting the entities.

Comment: I take it that the `AND` is the default boolean value. So do you know what `OR` would look like?

Comment: unfortunately "OR" queries are not supported, you are gonna have to do separate queries and merge the result yourself.